# Como autenticar a aplicação e autoriza-la a consumir uma restful API

Tags: php, restful, symfony-2, jwt

Em um determinado projeto, foi necessário criar uma restful API que recebe dados de vários formulários espalhados por vários sites alojados em diferentes servidores.

A API foi criada para resolver os seguintes problemas:

- Manutenção: ter uma única entrada de dados na base de dados.
- Segurança: uma vez que cada formulário grava diretamente na base de dados, há um problema enorme de segurança.

Em termos de conceito, o formulário é um app que funciona dentro do site de terceiros.

Cada formulário vai utilizar AngularJS para enviar os dados via POST.

O problema é que no momento a API não tem qualquer tipo de autenticação (calma, ainda está em desenvolvimento) e aqui surgiu a minha dúvida: **como identificar se os dados que a API recebe são de um formulário autorizado?**

No momento basta fazer um `POST` para o endpoint e os dados serão gravados e lógico que isso é um problema de segurança.

Pensei em utilizar o [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (Json Web Token) mas para isso seria necessário passar credenciais para obter um token, mas como estamos a utilizar AngularJS nos formulários, bastava inspecionar o código e retirar as credenciais.

No lado do servidor estou a usar [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) para construir a API.

Comment: Existem muitas maneiras de resolver seu problema de segurança. A mais simples delas na minha opinião é enviar no cabeçalho da requisição POST uma chave http-authorization, contendo um hash que identifique cada form (hash da url de origem por exemplo).

Comment: @touchmx mas essa chave facilmente poderia ser copiada e ser utilizada em um ataque CSRF.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho mas o IP pode ser "falsificado" e também é fácil obter o IP do servidor, logo não resolveria o problema.

Comment: Então é simples, implemente o Oauth2 na requisições. Se mesmo assim não for suficiente, implemente um sistema de chaves assimétricas. Um certificado SSL em cada domínio também ajuda.

Comment: @touchmx como o Oauth2 pode ajudar? Esse protocolo não é para usar quando o utilizador quer dar acesso aos seus dados a terceiros? Não é esse o meu caso, quero identificar se estou a receber dados de um formulário autorizado. O Oauth2 serve para esses casos também?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A meu ver você precisa implementar o mecanismo [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) ou proteção contra [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) na sua aplicação.

## CORS

Com CORS, você consegue definir quais são as origens que estão permitidas a executar determinadas ações na sua aplicação – como, por exemplo, submeter um formulário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Peguei a imagem [nesse link](https://dzone.com/articles/cross-site-requests-gwt).)

Por exemplo, suponha que o front-end de sua aplicação esteja no domínio site.com e o back-end esteja no domínio app.site.com. Antes do formulário ser efetivamente submetido, é feita uma requisição do tipo `OPTIONS` ao back-end (o que é chamado de *preflight*) afim de saber se o front-end realmente pode enviar aqueles dados. O back-end, então, responde com algo do tipo:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://site.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
```

Isso significa que apenas aplicações hospedadas no domínio site.com podem enviar requisições do tipo `POST` ao back-end. Qualquer outro tipo de requisição, ou requisições vindas de outras origens, receberão uma resposta com status `403 Forbidden`.

Vale notar que CORS é respeitado apenas por browsers mais modernos – se você tentar submeter o formulário usando um browser antigo ou por meio da linha de comando esse mecanismo não irá funcionar.

Como você está usando Symfony para desenvolver o back-end, recomendo que dê uma olhada nesse *bundle* que facilita a configuração do CORS em sua aplicação: [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle).

## CSRF

Um ataque por meio de CSRF, XSRF ou sea-surf se caracteriza pelo fato do usuário enviar dados maliciosos ao servidor sem seu consenso. Esses ataques podem ser facilmente evitados exigindo-se um *cookie* ou um valor postado válido somente para aquela submissão de dados ou uma série de submissões.

O Symfony possui proteção nativa contra ataques CSRF. Todos os formulários gerados por meio da aplicação possuem um campo oculto cujo valor é um hash válido somente para um determinado formulário dentro de uma determinada sessão, de modo que aplicações maliciosas não consigam obter esse valor.

Se você notar a classe `CsrfProviderInterface`, notará os seguintes métodos que implementam a proteção CSRF:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider;

/**
 * Marks classes able to provide CSRF protection
 *
 * You can generate a CSRF token by using the method generateCsrfToken(). To
 * this method you should pass a value that is unique to the page that should
 * be secured against CSRF attacks. This value doesn't necessarily have to be
 * secret. Implementations of this interface are responsible for adding more
 * secret information.
 *
 * If you want to secure a form submission against CSRF attacks, you could
 * supply an "intention" string. This way you make sure that the form can only
 * be submitted to pages that are designed to handle the form, that is, that use
 * the same intention string to validate the CSRF token with isCsrfTokenValid().
 *
 * @author Bernhard Schussek <bschussek@gmail.com>
 */
interface CsrfProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Generates a CSRF token for a page of your application.
     *
     * @param string $intention Some value that identifies the action intention
     *                          (i.e. "authenticate"). Doesn't have to be a secret value.
     */
    public function generateCsrfToken($intention);

    /**
     * Validates a CSRF token.
     *
     * @param string $intention The intention used when generating the CSRF token
     * @param string $token     The token supplied by the browser
     *
     * @return Boolean Whether the token supplied by the browser is correct
     */
    public function isCsrfTokenValid($intention, $token);
}
```

A implementação dessa interface, mostra que o token só é válido se ele foi gerado previamente:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider;

/**
 * Default implementation of CsrfProviderInterface.
 *
 * This provider uses the session ID returned by session_id() as well as a
 * user-defined secret value to secure the CSRF token.
 *
 * @author Bernhard Schussek <bschussek@gmail.com>
 */
class DefaultCsrfProvider implements CsrfProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * A secret value used for generating the CSRF token
     * @var string
     */
    protected $secret;

    /**
     * Initializes the provider with a secret value
     *
     * A recommended value for the secret is a generated value with at least
     * 32 characters and mixed letters, digits and special characters.
     *
     * @param string $secret A secret value included in the CSRF token
     */
    public function __construct($secret)
    {
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function generateCsrfToken($intention)
    {
        return sha1($this->secret.$intention.$this->getSessionId());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function isCsrfTokenValid($intention, $token)
    {
        return $token === $this->generateCsrfToken($intention);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ID of the user session.
     *
     * Automatically starts the session if necessary.
     *
     * @return string The session ID
     */
    protected function getSessionId()
    {
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4', '>=')) {
            if (PHP_SESSION_NONE === session_status()) {
                session_start();
            }
        } elseif (!session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }

        return session_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: Rodrigo, mas isso só funciona se o POST for feito via browser, se por exemplo, usar uma consola e fizer POST Request, esse bloqueio já não irá funcionar, certo?

Comment: Certo, a ideia do CORS é que ele seja um protocolo respeitado por browsers. Vou adaptar a resposta para comentar sobre CSRF também.